# Ubuntu 14.04 Stuck on Login

Tags: 14.04, login

I am having an issue with 14.04.

It was installed a couple days ago, however after the first cold restart, the issue arises.

I can get to the GRUB, then to login, but then I am stuck with the desktop background only.

***This is similar to other threads, but the difference is that I cannot access terminal at all.***

Pressing ctrl + alt + f(?) only yields a bright pink or dark purple screen with no text.

Thank You for the Help!

Comment: 1. Is the iso image of 14.04 that you download a good one? 2. Have you tried clearing that partition(s) and reinstall ubuntu agian? 3. How do you know its not the hard drive itself?

Comment: "*Pressing ctrl + alt + f(?) only yields a bright pink or dark purple screen with no text.*" That does suggest [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/q/17381) might *not* apply (or at least: the answers there are unusable without other steps first). Maybe something at [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/q/162075) may be helpful, such as the advice to try nomodeset or to boot from a different kernel. (The pre-upgrade kernels may still exist and be bootable.) I'm *not* saying this is a duplicate of either.

Answer (score 0):

With caution you can access terminal by going to "advance options for ubuntu" at grub, select the top most or only "ubuntu, with linux 3.x.x... generic (recovery mode)" and when in the recovery menu select "Drop to root Terminal."

Comment: Is this a very risky option? I'd rather not do anything that would potentially put my system in danger. If the safest route is to uninstall and reinstall, then so be it. Otherwise, is there any other way to fix this?

Comment: I don't know man your installation problems seem pretty bad so unless you have files on your ubuntu partition(s) I would just reinstall ubuntu on that/those partition(s). I had a problem like that when a compiz update went bad, but I could fall back into the command line interface with ctrl + alt + f1 and back out with ctrl + alt + f7. I was lazy and didn't want to complete my research on the issue so I just reinstalled ubuntu (my personal files where backup though).It also do not hurt to have scripts to install all your programs and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04 in xubuntu.

After selecting Ubuntu in GRUB I would be stuck on the splash screen that is displayed before the login screen.

I was able to boot into single user mode and get access to the terminal by doing the following:

1. While in GRUB I would move the selector over Ubuntu
2. Press 'e'
3. Move the cursor down to the "linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic root=UUID...."  line
4. Append the word " single" at the end of this line
5. Press F10
6. You will now be in a terminal with root access (be careful)